# Application wide Constant on Application Load in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wish to read a yaml file, deserialize it and store it as a constant till tne next time the website is rebuilt again in ASP.NET C#.

What would be the way to do it in ASP.NET C#?

Comment: "The best way" is opinion-based if you don't supply any criteria. Also, a constant is probably not what you're looking for, as a constant's contents must be known at compile-time. What have you searched, what did you find? Are you just looking for "any way"? Then see for example [Storing variable value for lifetime in .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081074/storing-variable-value-for-lifetime-in-net).

Comment: Or do you really want a constant as in a class, for example using a pre or post build script?

Answer (score 0):

Application start in Global.asax.

Read in the file and store as a static variable. Use a lock to avoid multithreading issues when modifying that variable (i.e. the initial load).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29

Answer (score 0):

You could read in the file in and generate code for a class to hold data as a constant. Write a script to compile the class to a dll. Then you need a reference and using statement in whatever program is using this configuration. You would need to run the scripts each time the site was built.